# Error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" in solving travelling salesman

Tags: r, subset, graph-algorithm

I’m studying R programming language and I tried to use it to calculate the distance between some places I will visit in my next trip to Portugual, but I’m in trouble in retrieving the data from dataframe.

I built a data file with this fields

- INITIAL_MONUMENT;
- FINAL_MONUMENT;
- DISTANCE;
- INITIAL_CITY;
- FINAL_CITY;
- INITIAL_REGION;
- FINAL_REGION;
- INITIAL_DISTRICT;
- FINAL_DISTRICT;

where the prefix *INITIAL_* indicates the places where I go from and the prefix *FINAL_* indicates the places where I arrive.

To simplified the calculus as first step of my small project, I’m concentrating to visit only the capital (Lisboa).

I declare a *vector* with all the monuments in Lisboa I want to use a for cycle over the monuments.

For every monument, I calculate the nearest monument using the *min()* function to field **DISTANCE**

This is my source code:

```
#read my csv
dataPortugal <- "D:/workspaceR/prove/principiante/resources/viaggi/monuments-portugual.csv"
portugual = read.table(header=TRUE,sep=';',file = dataPortugal)
#names of columns: the instruction gives me the result I expect
colnames(portugual)
[1] "INITIAL_MONUMENT" "FINAL_MONUMENT"   "DISTANCE"         "INITIAL_CITY"     "FINAL_CITY"       "INITIAL_REGION"   "FINAL_REGION"   
 [8] "INITIAL_DISTRICT" "FINAL_DISTRICT"   "X"              

#I concentrare only in monuments in Lisboa city: the instruction gives me the result I expect
only_lisbona <- portugual[portugual$INITIAL_CITY == "LISBONA" & portugual$FINAL_CITY == "LISBONA",]

#I delete the useless columns in case of my current single city: the instruction gives me the result I expect
only_lisbona <- subset(only_lisbona, select = c(1,2,3))

#I have a list of all possible monuments in Lisboa: the instruction gives me the result I expect
allMonuments <-(only_lisbona %>% distinct(INITIAL_MONUMENT))

myTrip <- #vector with the shortest trip from a monument to another

visitedPlaces <-#vector with the monuments I elaborated

#I consider every monument as departure to another monument
 for(currentDeparture in allMonuments){
 #I have a list of possible arrival Monuments
 moreArrivals <- subset(only_lisbona, INITIAL_MONUMENT == currentDeparture)# ERROR

 #after this point
 #it's a draft of code
 # it's not a part of my question
   minimun <- min(moreArrivals)$DISTANCE

  if(0 <minimun){

    myTrip[currentDeparture] <- minimun

    ...#SET VISITED THE FINAL MONUMENT

     for(currentDestination in allMonuments){

       visitedPlaces<-subset(only_lisbona, INITIAL_MONUMENT == currentDeparture & FINAL_MONUMENT == currentDestination

                             & DISTANCE == minimun)
     }
   }else{
     #TODO
   }

}
```

I want
cycle every monument (*for* cycle)
the current monument is a point of departure for other monuments 
the actual next monuments to visit is the monument with mininum distance  from actual departure monument (I'm using a subset, filtered by INITIAL_MONUMENT equal to current departure)

But, in the line where I put the comment #ERROR, the console gives me this error message

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
>
> only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In `==.default`(INITIAL_MONUMENT, currentDeparture) :
>
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>
> 2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
>
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

This error means that I’m valorizing in wrong way my set of destination monuments *moreArrivals*, but in which other way I can storage the subset of destination from a particular departure?

Note: I think it's a similar problem of [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem): I have a list of places to visit with different distance and I would to optimize the distance and touch one time every place.

Thank you

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your *warnings* clearly indicate that you are comparing two vectors of different size. This can't be what you intend, so you need to fix your code. The *error* is also quite clear. You are passing a data.frame where some columns are not numeric to a function that doesn't accept such input.

Comment: Thank you, I wish to give the points of correct response but I can't. If ou want you can copy your  comment as response. Thank you